# Reason for using "Hash.new { Hash.new(false) }"

Tags: ruby, hash

Encountered some code which sets an instance variable like so:

```rb
@square_array = Hash.new { Hash.new(false) }
```

Is there a reason to do it this way?

Rather then one of the following:

```rb
@square_array = Hash.new 

# or

@square_array = {}
```

Comment: Presumably, the hash is used in some way that needs the default value.

Comment: @JörgWMittag _transient_ default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason. If you define hash with `{}` and try to get value of non-existing key, you get `nil`

```
hash = {}
#=> {}
hash[:a]
#=> nil
```

But if you define it with `Hash.new` you can set define value for non-existing key

```
hash =  Hash.new { Hash.new(false) }
#=> {}
hash[:a]
#=> {}
hash[:a][:a]
#=> false
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that the code has a subtle bug and probably doesn't function as intended. `Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(false) }` is probably what they should be using or there should be a comment that they really do mean it to not store the default.